# Unindexed remote maven resitories in intellij IDEA 15.0.1

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle

While creating new Gradle project in Intellij Idea 15.0.1,

I get the following error :
[image]

And when I try to update the repository in Repositories List, I get the following exception :
[image]

When I searched for this problem, I came across some posts stating that it was a known issues which was to be fixed in the previous versions (14. something) but apparently it isn't fixed, or it is not a bug.
[Some](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102693) also advised to uncheck "use maven3 to import project" in File -> Settings -> maven -> importing, but can't find that option:
[image]

Seems like the problem is with the internet connection, when I use my mobile hotspot sharing phone's cellular data, the updating start, but since it has to sync around 260MB data, it was too slow. But when I use the LAN provided by the school which uses proxy it gives the aforementioned error right away.

I've configured the http proxy in settings and connection seems okay.

Is this error (Unindexed remote maven repositories found) something to worry about, if I am able to download the dependencies? Any way to fix this?

Comment: You don't need to care much about this error. It will only prevent the IDE from autocompleting group and artifact IDs when adding a dependency to your gradle build file or maven pom.xml.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle`, substitute:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

or perhaps:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Close and reopen your IDEA project.